# Slow Motion Video with Audio using frames approach - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-audio

I have to convert video to slow motion with audio using frame base approach. 
Following links were lot of help which are 
[Reverse-AVAsset-Efficient](https://github.com/whydna/Reverse-AVAsset-Efficient)

In solution I can change the timestamp of the buffer and achieve slow motion video.

```
for sample in videoSamples {
   var presentationTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sample)

   //Changing Timestamp to achieve slow-motion 
   presentationTime.timescale = presentationTime.timescale * 2

   let imageBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sample)
   while !videoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
     Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
   }
   pixelBufferAdaptor.append(imageBufferRef!, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
}
```

for audio slow motion I tried to change the timestamp of audio sample but it has no effect.

Is there any solution for Audio slow-motion.

If you have Objective-C solution, feel free to post it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do an easy slow motion using `AVMutableComposition`. As @hotpaw2 mentioned, there is more than one way to slow down your audio - for example you could lower the pitch or keep it constant. This solution seems to keep it constant and I don't see any way to change that. Maybe that's what you want. Maybe not.

You can use `AVAssetExportSession` to write the slow video out to a file, and since 
`AVMutableComposition` is (perhaps surprisingly) a subclass of `AVAsset`, you can preview the results using `AVPlayer` even if you haven't exported the slow motion version of the video.

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mp4")! , options : nil)

let srcVideoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!
let srcAudioTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first!

let sloMoComposition = AVMutableComposition()
let sloMoVideoTrack = sloMoComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!
let sloMoAudioTrack = sloMoComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!

let assetTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration)

try! sloMoVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(assetTimeRange, of: srcVideoTrack, at: .zero)
try! sloMoAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(assetTimeRange, of: srcAudioTrack, at: .zero)

let newDuration = CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(assetTimeRange.duration, multiplier: 2)
sloMoVideoTrack.scaleTimeRange(assetTimeRange, toDuration: newDuration)
sloMoAudioTrack.scaleTimeRange(assetTimeRange, toDuration: newDuration)

// you can play sloMoComposition in an AVPlayer at this point

// Export to a file using AVAssetExportSession
let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: sloMoComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)!
exportSession.outputFileType = .mp4
exportSession.outputURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("slow-mo-\(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate).mp4")
exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
    assert(exportSession.status == .completed)
    print("File in \(exportSession.outputURL!)")
}
```

Comment: See my answer for additional information on how to also change the pitch strategy

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want the audio to sound like, you can try using manually feeding one of Apple's time pitch Audio Units with the audio sample data to change its length to match the time between your new time stamps.

Comment: I simply want slow/fast motion video that contains slow motion audio too. Changing the video frames working fine, but audio is not.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Gordon Child's answer, once you have what he described, you can indeed change the pitch correction strategy for the composition through using the AudioMix infrastructure as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67585868/15285041), because AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters has a settable AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithm.  I confirmed that this works.

```
let audioTracks = composition.tracks(withMediaType: .audio) // AVMutableComposition
var trackMixArray = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters]()
for audioTrack in audioTracks {
    var trackMix = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: audioTrack)
    trackMix.audioTimePitchAlgorithm = .varispeed
    trackMix.setVolume(volume, at: .zero)
}
trackMixArray.append(trackMix)
let audioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
audioMix.inputParameters = trackMixArray
export.audioMix = audioMix // AVAssetExportSession
```

Comment: please expand this into a full answer post