# Is there any way for me to speed up audio from another app with Swift?

Tags: swift

What I am trying to do is speed up audio from audiobooks I listen to with another application. When I am listening to an audiobook, is there any code that would allow me to jump into my app and speed up the audio from another app? I am getting tired of 2x speed and I would like to speed up to 8x if possible.

Comment: Depends on what application. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I am working on an application right now, it would be a personal application and simply all that it does is allow me to speed up audio from podcasts or audiobooks I am listening to. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well speeding up audio shouldn't be hard, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61678521/14351818).

Comment: Will this allow me to speed up audio from other applications? In this case I am trying not to have to download the audio, an example is listening to the music app on my phone, then heading to my app and clicking a button that doubles the playback speed because the music app doesn't allow you to speed up music.

Comment: It will be different depending on the app. Most of them wouldn’t allow you to access the audio. You will need to look into each app’s APIs, if they have any. But in general, this would be hard to do. Apps are sandboxed on iOS and have limited ways to contact each other.

Comment: I have used api's a few times, an example of what I most want to speed up is audiobooks from an app called Libby. How would I go about trying to access its audio?

Comment: As far as I know, it might not be possible